# Contractible nullhomotopy

Tags: homotopy-theory

> If $X$ is a contractible space, then for every neighborhood $W$ of $*$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $*$ such that $U \subseteq W$ and $U$ is contractible in $W$.

My book's proof:

Let $\text{id} \simeq_F *: X \to X$. Then $F(*,t) = * \in W$ and so by continuity of $F$, there exist neighborhoods $U_t$ of $*$ and $V_t$ of $t$ such that $F(U_t \times V_t) \subseteq W.$ Clearly $\{V_t\}_{t \in I}$ covers $I.$ By compactness of $I$, there is a finite sub cover $V_{t_1}, \ldots, V_{t_n}$, and we set $U = \bigcap U_{t_i}.$ It follows that $F|U \times I: U \times I \to W$ is the desired nullhomotopy of the inclusion map.

**Question**

Firstly, why is it clear that $\{V_t\}_{t \in I}$ covers $I$? Does cover mean span? Secondly what does the "$|$" symbol mean when they write $F|U \times I: U \times I \to W$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cover" means "cover". Just to show two examples, it might be that $V_{0.5}=(0.4,0.7)$ and $V_{0.9}=(0.75,1]$ (note that the first one contains $0.5$ and the second one contains $0.9$; that's what $V_t$ bring a neighbourhood of $t$ signifies). The main point is that *every* point $a\in I$ is contained in some $V$ (specifically $V_a$), which means that the infinite union of all $V_t$ is the whole unit interval.

The vertical bar means "restricted to". If you have any function $f:A\to B$ and $A'\subseteq A$ is any subset, then $f|_A$ is the function that takes as input points $a\in A'$ and send it to $f(a)\in B$.

Comment: Oh, so the coverings $V_t$ are intervals that contain $t$?

Comment: @user19405892 $V_t$ covers $t$, and since there is a $V_t$ for _every_ $t \in I$, it means that all of the $V_t$ together cover $I$.

Comment: I still don't really get the restricted to definition. Is the restriction with respect to a subset of the domain?

Comment: @user19405892 Yes. It's still basically the same function. You just limit the valid input points / domain (from $X\times I$ to $U\times I$), which means it's _technically_ a new and different function. It is, however, so tightly connected to $F$ that it merits a special notation to demonstrate this connection (rather than just calling it $G$).

Comment: Can you elaborate why the $F$ they give is the desired nullhomotopy? We would need $\text{id}_U$ to be nullhomotopic.

Comment: @user19405892 Because $F(U_t\times V_t)\subseteq W$ for any $t$, and because $U\times I\subseteq \bigcup_t U_t\times V_t$.

Comment: I don't see how that implies the identity is nullhomtopic.

Comment: @user19405892 It implies that $F(U\times I) \subseteq W$, which is _exactly_ saying that the identity function on $U$ is nullhomotopic inside $W$ (since $F$ was a nullhomotopy of the identity function on $X$ in the first place).

Comment: What would be  wrong if we said $F: U \times I \to W$ instead of $F| U \times I: U \times I \to W$? Also what is the inclusion map they are referring to?

Comment: The inclusion map they're referring to is $\iota: U\to X$. And you can't say $F: U\times I \to W$, because $F$ is a function from $X\times I$ to $X$, and you can't change that. What you _can_ do, however, is to use $F$ to construct a new function that goes from $U\times I$ and show that the image is contained in $W$. That function is what they call $F|_{U\times I}:U\times I \to W$.

Comment: So the inclusion map is nullhomotopic to the base point with the homotopy $F$?

Comment: Yes, and it is nullhomotopic _inside_ $W$.

Comment: I am still a little confused how $F(U \times I) \subseteq W$ says that the identity function on $U$ is nullhomotopic in $W$.

Comment: For any $u \in U$ we have: $$F(u, 0) = u\\F(u, 1) = *\\\forall t \in [0,1] \quad F(u, t) \in W$$That is more or less the definition of "$F$ is a homotopy between the inclusion $U \hookrightarrow W$ and the constant map $U \to *$" (with the restriction symbol supressed for readability).

Comment: Can you help with this question too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1730821/contractible-nullhomotopy